# Thinking Sphinx indexes declaration as a symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am indexing about 200M rows and 10 columns of data with Thinking Sphinx 3, Sphinx 2, Rails 4, and PostgreSQL 9, and my generated index data was about 250GB, or a little over 1GB per 1M rows.

Initially, I had my indices declared as symbols, such as `indexes :short_description`, but when I took out the semi-colon, and re-indexed as follows: `indexes short_description`, my index data dropped to 68G, or about 340MB per 1M rows.

Two questions:

1) Which is technical correct, a symbol or a string (or does it matter)?

2) With only 68GB, am I now missing some of my data, or was the 250GB of indexes just a fluke?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

There is theoretically no difference between the symbol version (`indexes :short_description`) and the method version (`indexes short_description`) of the index calls. The symbol version was initially built into Thinking Sphinx as a workaround for existing instance methods on Ruby's `Object` class (e.g. `id`) - but since Ruby 1.9, BasicObject has close to no instance methods defined on it, and so index definitions can be interpreted with close to no confusion. Thus, the method approach - which has *always* existed in Thinking Sphinx - is what I recommend (and what I use all the time in my own projects).

Thus:

1. It doesn't matter, but I'd recommend using the method approach.
2. Given it shouldn't matter, I'm really surprised at the difference in index size (any difference is odd - such a massive difference is particularly confusing).

It's probably worth checking the `sql_query` SQL command generated for the index/source in both cases - if they're different, then it sounds like there's a bug in Thinking Sphinx.